# Expanding from dashing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, dashing

I am fiddling around with Dashing until I found that it only has **one dashboard-level action**. [[link]](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/6c6d71cee1056be596af40921761eeebee368828/javascripts/dashing.coffee)

The Dashing project does not have the [dashing.coffee](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/6c6d71cee1056be596af40921761eeebee368828/javascripts/dashing.coffee) file in the directory but it links to it. The reload action is contained here.

```
class window.Dashing extends Batman.App
  @on 'reload', (data) ->
    window.location.reload(true)

  @root ->
Dashing.params = Batman.URI.paramsFromQuery(window.location.search.slice(1));
```

I want to expand this file to add more actions. I tried creating a JS file dashing-cus.coffee on my local dashboard in an attempt to build more actions. However, my attempts results to either prototype errors or non-responding actions.

What is the best way to expand its actions? Let's say an 'alert' action to alert 'hello!'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why and if you really want to rewrite `Dashing` class.

But the best way to do it is using just a copy of `dashing.coffee` inside your project as `./assets/javascript/dashing-cus.coffee` and replacing [that line](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/blob/master/templates/project/assets/javascripts/application.coffee#L3) for:

```
 #= require dashing-cus.coffee
```

On `dashing-cus.coffee` you can customize `window.Dashing` as you want, because the original Dashing script will not be used anymore...